# Bumblebee xb3 and stereo_image_proc

Tags: ros, camera, camera-info-manager, bumblebee, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I have a question about stereo_image_proc and camera info manager.

I am using the Bumblebee xb3 camera, wich have 3 lenses. I need to get two pairs of images from the camera. One pair with the right and the center lenses (namespace=xb3_short), and another with right and left lenses (namespace=xb3_wide).

In order to run stereo image proc i need this topics:

```
xb3_short/left/image_raw                                                            
xb3_short/left/camera_info                                                    
xb3_short/right/image_raw                                         
xb3_short/right/camera_info                                                      
                                                                                  
xb3_wide/left/image_raw                                                              
xb3_wide/left/camera_info                                                          
xb3_wide/right/image_raw                                                        
xb3_wide/right/camera_info
```

But actually xb3_short/right/image_raw and xb3_wide/right/image_raw are the same images. This will result a extra space when i need to record bag files with the camera. Is there a way to record only 3 images instead of 4?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33096/bumblebee-xb3-and-stereo_image_proc/) by [Talhada](https://answers.ros.org/users/2188/talhada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably not relevant, but yes: you can [cherry-pick on the topics you want to be recorded in a rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data#Recording_a_subset_of_the_data).

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1